# Laravel Sync username into pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, pivot, pivot-table, laravel-7

I have an extra column for usernames in my `role_user` pivot table, how can I sync the username with the roles ?

`role_user` pivot table

[image]

I need to sync the user name in the `name` field

This is the update function where I have added the `sync`

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
       
        $role = $request->role;

        $userName = Auth::user();

        $user->roles()->sync([$role=>['name'=>$userName->name]]);

        dd('stop'); 
   }
```

Here's the relationship in my `User Model`

```
 public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class)->withPivot(['name'])->withTimestamps();
}
```

Here's the `role_user` table migration

```
 class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
    }
}
```

I got this error if when I tried
[image]

This is what i get when i dump the request and Auth user name

[image]

Dump codes

```
  $userName = Auth::user();

    dump('Auth user name  = '.$userName->name);

    dump($request->all());

    dd('stop');
```

Comment: wouldn't you want `$user->name` instead of `$userName->name` ... since `$user` is the user for that id you are adding to the pivot table?

Comment: can you print what are you sending in request? are we sure you are logged in and auth()->user() doesn't return `null`? and make sure `$request->role` is `id` of role or it won't work.

Comment: @lagbox well variable naming has some problems here, since $userName represents User object, $userName->name makes sense.

Comment: well we don't know how your Auth is setup ... but the authenticated user is not the same as the user you are syncing the role for potentially, why do you want the current authenticated user's name for someone else's user id?

Comment: @lagbox I have updated the question, I need the Auth user name to be added to the pivot table.

Comment: `$role` is an array, not a single value (arrays can't be array keys), you will have to adjust how you build the array passed to `sync`

Comment: @lagbox So is there any way that i can pass thee Auth user name with the array to the pivot table, please  suggest me a way

Comment: you will have to make a correct array to pass to `sync`

Comment: @lagbox I need to know how can i make a correct array ?

Comment: the docs show you how the array would look, try to follow what it says, if not we can figure something out

Comment: @lagbox when i used `attach` it works fine, but i need to use `sync` since attach will make duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an associative array keyed by the role id with an array for each element to add things to the pivot table. Currently you just have an array of role ids, which is fine for `sync` as is, but not if you want to also set the extra pivot data. You need an array like:

```
[1 => ['name' => ...], 2 => ['name' => ...]]
```

You can use `array_fill_keys` to build this array with the keys being the role ids and the values being the array with the 'name' field:

```
$roles = (array) $request->input('role', []);

$forSync = array_fill_keys($roles, ['name' => $userName->name]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the above codes worked, i have edited the lines

Answer (score 1):

Ok you **almost** done it correct. except..

You need to write it like this ( using [Collection mapWithKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys) method):

```php
$roles = collect($request->role)->mapWithKeys(function($role){
    return [$role => ['name' => Auth::user()->name];
})->toArray();

$user->roles()->sync($roles);
```

the reason for this is that you need to specify pivot table parameters for each role separately. so instead of `[[1,2] => ['name' => 'John']]` you need to have `[1 => ['name' => 'John'],2 => ['name' => 'John']]` for it to work.

Comment: This codes works as well, Thank you very much